Is this loop pattern with two end pointers a missed optimization?
With Clang -O3, the function f1
typedef unsigned char u8;

u8 f1(u8* p, u8* end1, u8* end2)
{
    while (p < end1 && p < end2) {
        if (*p & 0x80)
            return 0xff;
        p++;
    }
    return 0x7f;
}

compiles to
f1:                                     # @f1
        cmp     rdi, rsi
        setae   cl
        cmp     rdi, rdx
        setae   r8b
        mov     al, 127
        or      r8b, cl
        jne     .LBB0_6
        inc     rdi
.LBB0_4:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        cmp     byte ptr [rdi - 1], 0
        js      .LBB0_5
        cmp     rdi, rsi
        jae     .LBB0_6
        lea     rcx, [rdi + 1]
        cmp     rdi, rdx
        mov     rdi, rcx
        jb      .LBB0_4
.LBB0_6:
        ret
.LBB0_5:
        mov     al, -1
        ret

while the function f2
u8 f2(u8* p, u8* end1, u8* end2)
{
    if (end2 < end1)
        end1 = end2;
    while (p < end1) {
        if (*p & 0x80)
            return 0xff;
        p++;
    }
    return 0x7f;
}

compiles to
f2:                                     # @f2
        cmp     rdx, rsi
        cmovb   rsi, rdx
        mov     al, 127
        cmp     rsi, rdi
        jbe     .LBB1_4
.LBB1_2:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        cmp     byte ptr [rdi], 0
        js      .LBB1_3
        inc     rdi
        cmp     rdi, rsi
        jb      .LBB1_2
.LBB1_4:
        ret
.LBB1_3:
        mov     al, -1
        ret

which has less instructions in the loop.
With GCC -O3 generated code is different but similar, there're more instructions in f1's loop.
Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/edb5Eda5b
Is there corner case that prevents the compiler from optimizing f1 as f2, e.g. are they nonequivalent?
Or is it a balance/trade-off to provide a close mapping from source code to binary code so that developers have more control?
I tried adding assumptions like ASSUME(p <= end1 && p <= end2) but nothing changed.

It is something you can report to the clang developers. Also bear in mind that f1 && f2 are different

How would that assumption add any information relevant for optimzing the loop in f1 differently?

@gulpr I'd like to be sure if f1 and f2 are equivalent according to as-if rule.

@Gerhardh As far as I can tell, no, just a blind try in case I missed something.

pointers that are not pointing to members of the same object or elements of the same array have no well defined ordering.  Afaik in principle you can have a < b and b < c and at the same time c < a. I dont think the two version are not equivalent

You added both C and C++ tag. Are you interested in C++ or C? You should not add both tags unless you want to mix them or want to know differences which both isn't the case in your question. AFAIR, theoretically, in C++ you could define crazy comparison operators that modify the object.

@Gerhardh you cannot overload operators for unsigned char, though I agree. I wouldnt be surprised if the answer is different for the two

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I am not sure if that makes a difference, but it is not about unsigned char but about unsigned char *. Is the same limitation valid there as well?

@Gerhardh I'm interested in both.

@Gerhardh yes for pointers same

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Ok then what if with adding ASSUME(p <= end1 && p <= end2) to both versions? It seems rule out that case.

If p < end1 is true at the start of the function and end2 is a null pointer, then f1 has defined behavior but f2 does not. This is because evaluation of p < end1 will immediately terminate the loop in f1, and it will return 0x7f, but, in f2, end1 < end2 will be evaluated, and that has undefined behavior. This does not mean we cannot craft assembly code for f1 that optimizes it in the way suggested by f2, but it may interfere with the compiler’s analysis and optimization unless this issue was specifically addressed in its algorithms.

what is ASSUME ?

For example, ASSUME(expr) is if (!(expr)) return 0;

its not true that adding if (!(p <= end1 && p <= end2)) return 0; changes nothing. https://godbolt.org/z/43GsM6T1n

@463035818_is_not_an_ai yes return 0 changes something but not the loops. if __builtin_unreachable() is used instead of return 0 then nothing changes. I used return 0 here to avoid non-standard thing.

how do you expect others to help when you say "I did A but nothing changes" but in reality you did B and something did change (but not the loops)?

with the "assert" clang produces identical output for f1 and f2 unless I miss something

sorry. I should have made it clear. I did tried both __builtin_unreachable(), abort() and return 0 in reality, replied with abort() and then somehow wanted to avoid non-standard stuff and to simplified as possible, so I deleted the comment with abort() and added the comment with return 0. Anyway I should always have made it clearer, sorry.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai by with the "assert" do you mean https://godbolt.org/z/9v51sEK91? they're not identical. Edit: diff view: https://godbolt.org/z/Tzv1K4b3b

no I mean this https://godbolt.org/z/jnTPWjqs5

@463035818_is_not_an_ai but they're not identical, diff view: https://godbolt.org/z/8WzeT9PGn   the loops are same as OP: there're 8 instructions(3 cmps) in f1's loop and 5 instructions(2 cmps) in f2's loop

Both are inefficient if you iterate on a large memory areas. I expect the compiler to vectorize and possibly unroll such loop, but they are often afraid of the break statement while loops and pointers aliasing. On modern x86-64 platforms, you can do AND for the mask and a OR to aggregate the bit set and then a PTEST (possibly using AVX-2 or even AVX-512 if available). SSE registers can contain 16 u8 items, AVX-2 32 u8, and AVX-512 64! The overhead of adding a condition which is very predictable is not really a problem then. For small arrays, your manual optimization makes sense.

@JérômeRichard Indeed. I found the difference when I was trying to align the pointer for "vectorization" and use these loop patterns for the small unaligned part. The best way I can see is to unroll the small unaligned part to a jump-table(switch).

I do not expect memory alignment to impact a compiler like Clang on this code. Jump tables tend to prevent vectorizing the code using SIMD instructions and add indirections that is harder for CPU to predict. This is the kind of optimization which is only worth it for very small arrays or operations that cannot be vectorized using SIMD instructions. You can certainly help Clang to use such instructions by operating on small chunks having a fixed-size defined at compile time (AFAIK Clang likes to aggressively vectorize loops <64 items). Btw, this remove the break optimization issue.
